# Regex matching returns several capturing block

Tags: python, regex

I wanted to extract experience from some line of text. It may contain some variation of years and months. I tried to make two non-capturing blocks using regex but it ends up in giving me several capturing instance.

```
Work Experience: 15 years 2 months
```

regex is:

```
((?:\d{1,3}(?:\.)?(?:\d{1})?\s+year(?:s)?\s+)?(?:\d{1,3}\s+month(?:s)?)?)
```

Though it captured the string that I want to find and it returns spurious matches as well.

One way to simply join the all instance as rest of matches are `''` but that will not be justice to coding practice.

I need a small help to figure out where did I go wrong?

Apologies,
I have missed one scenario which has led to putting everyone off track. there are strings which are like

```
2 Months
1 year 3 months
1.5 year
15 year 2 months
```

Comment: Try it like this `\b\d+ years? \d{1,3} months?\b` https://regex101.com/r/xhGYKc/1

Comment: As an aside, `{1}` is always useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern matches a position before and after each character as well because all the parts in the pattern are optional.

You can write these parts like `(?:s)?` just as `s?` and you can omit `{1}`

---

If you don't want to match empty strings, you could either match an optional year part followed by the months, or match the months part.

You could either use a case insensitive match or match either a lowercase chars and upper case char using a character class `[yY]`

As you want the match only, you can omit the capturing group.

```
\b(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)? years? )?\d{1,3} months?\b|\b\d+(?:\.\d+)? years?\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\b(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)? years? )?` Match an optional year part with optional decimal part
- `\d{1,3} months?\b` Match the month part with 1-3 digits
- `|` Or
- `\b\d+(?:\.\d+)? years?\b` Match the years part

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/L9mAtD/1)

**Note** that `\s` could also match a newline

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce your regex as below to capture only those groups that required. here `\1` will have required string.
This will also match string separated with tabs and newlines.

```regex
^\D*((?:[\d.]+\s*[yY]ears?)?\s*(?:[\d.]+\s*[mM]onths?)?)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vPa3MC/3)